# How can I generate a picture using switch and cases?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, switch-statement

Here is what I have so far. The `newNumber` is a function I made just to do min and max. I am really having trouble with this.

```
function onclick() {
        var num = parseFloat(document.getElementById("do").value);
        if (num <= 0) {
            alert("Please enter a bet amount between 1 and 100");
        }
        else if (num > 100) {
            alert("Please enter a bet amount between 1 and 100");
        }

        var stake = document.getElementById("txtStake").value;
        if (stake < num) {
            alert("Wrong number Can't Be Higher Than Stake Number")
        }

        var random = newNumber(1, 7);

        if (random == 1) {
            document.getElementById("toChangeColor").style.backgroundColor = "red";                
        }
        else if (random == 2) {
            document.getElementById("toChangeColor").style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
        else if (random == 3) {
            document.getElementById("toChangeColor").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
        }
        else if (random == 4) {
            document.getElementById("toChangeColor").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        }
        else if (random == 5) {
            document.getElementById("toChangeColor").style.backgroundColor = "brown";
        }
        else if (random == 6) {
            document.getElementById("toChangeColor").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        }
        else if (random == 7) {
            document.getElementById("toChangeColor").style.backgroundColor = "black";
        }

        switch (random) {
            case 1:
                document.getElementById("picture").src = "time.jpg";
                break;
            case 2:
                document.getElementById("picture").src = "pic2.jpg";
                break;
            case 3:
                document.getElementById("picture").src = "pic3.jpg";
                break;
            case 4:
                document.getElementById("picture").src = "pic4.jpg";
                break;
            case 5:
                document.getElementById("picture").src = "pic5.jpg";
                break;
            case 6:
                document.getElementById("picture").src = "pic6.jpg";
                break;
            case 7:
                document.getElementById("picture").src = "pic7.jpg";
                break;
        }
    }
```

When I click a button I need a random picture out of 5 choices to display in a certain area. How can I do this using switch or loop?

Comment: What have you tried - show us some code that you have attempted.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: All I did was make the switch statement :

Comment: Why would you consider a loop to make a single selection? I wouldn't use a switch for this either, I'd put the available choices in an array and then randomly select one item from that array.

Comment: switch (variable name):

Comment: case 1: case:2 case:3

Comment: in each case i added the image src and said where it appears

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the actual function you've tried, don't post it bit by bit in comments.

Comment: My teacher didn't teach us Array so i didn't know

Comment: OK. Well a switch certainly can be used to do it, it's just not what I would choose. If what you've already tried didn't work, please [edit] your question to show your attempt and we can help explain how to fix it. From your comments it sounds like you're at least halfway there already.

Comment: Thank you! i updated the question

Comment: can you teach me how to use switch exactly? I feel like I am doing something wrong

Comment: Please do simple research: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: The switch statement shown in your updated question is syntactically correct and should work - it works here: https://jsfiddle.net/dhk1uz0d/. In practice you wouldn't use both the switch *and* the if/else if/else structure when they're both testing the same `random` variable, but that doesn't mean it wouldn't work. Does the rest of your function work the way you expect it to? What happens when you actually run your code?

Answer (score 0):

Your situation to write switch or if case will be redundant, just make in an array or two-dimensional array will be better.

```
var bgColors = ['red', 'green', 'yelow'];
var pics = ['time.jpg', 'pic2.jpg', 'pic3.jpg'];

var randomIndex = newNumber(0, 2);

document.getElementById("toChangeColor").style.backgroundColor = bgColors[randomIndex];
document.getElementById("picture").src = pics[randomIndex];
```